# Why tesseract give junk value for japanese language?

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract, cjk

I am using below code for read japanese language.
but it give junk character even it convert in unicode.
Can you guide me how to make it correct?

```
void Test(char* imagePath)
{
    char *outText;

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    // Initialize tesseract-ocr with English, without specifying tessdata path
    if (api->Init("D:\\tessdata", "jpn", tesseract::OcrEngineMode::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Open input image with leptonica library
    Pix *image = pixRead(imagePath);
    api->SetImage(image);
    // Get OCR result
    outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
    printf("OCR output:\n%s", outText);

    // Destroy used object and release memory
    api->End();
    delete[] outText;
    pixDestroy(&image);
}
```

Using the test data from below link
https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata

Test image
[image]

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: char * output : æ—¥ä»˜
è«‹æ±‚æ›¸      Unicode : 韦颻讫뇦뢛ਊ 4

Comment: Your output is correct UTF-8: `E6 97 A5 E4 BB 98 20 E8 AB 8B E6 B1 82 E6 B1 82 E6 9B B8` =日付 請求書

Comment: Yes thanks for your answer